# How to use socket.io-client in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, socket.io, laravel-echo

Server side is php laravel echo websocket and I am trying to connect by Angular 4. I tried using ng2-socket-io - npm and also laravel-echo - npm but none of them were successfully. If anyone know any documentation or tutorial how I can use it, please help

Answer (score 38):

Hi @giga Working example is given below.

**SETUP**

```
npm i socket.io-client --save
npm i @types/socket.io-client --save
```

**Server-side (nodejs)**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var port = 8000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
console.log('new connection made');

socket.on('event1', (data) => {
  console.log(data.msg);
});

socket.emit('event2', {
  msg: 'Server to client, do you read me? Over.'
});

socket.on('event3', (data) => {
  console.log(data.msg);
  socket.emit('event4', {
    msg: 'Loud and clear :)'
  });
});
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Listening on port " + port);
});
```

**Client-side - Angular4 code**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'ch-home',
    styleUrls: ['home.styles.css'],
    templateUrl: 'home.template.html'
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    messageText: string;
    messages: Array<any>;
    socket: SocketIOClient.Socket;

  constructor() {
   // this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
   this.socket = io.connect();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
        this.messages = new Array();

        this.socket.on('message-received', (msg: any) => {
            this.messages.push(msg);
            console.log(msg);
            console.log(this.messages);
        });
      this.socket.emit('event1', {
          msg: 'Client to server, can you hear me server?'
      });
      this.socket.on('event2', (data: any) => {
        console.log(data.msg);
        this.socket.emit('event3', {
            msg: 'Yes, its working for me!!'
        });
      });
      this.socket.on('event4', (data: any) => {
          console.log(data.msg);
      });
   }

   sendMessage() {
    const message = {
      text: this.messageText
    };
    this.socket.emit('send-message', message);
    // console.log(message.text);
    this.messageText = '';
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you that was helpfull

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52702054/how-to-auto-reconnect-socket-io-without-refresh-page-from-angular can u help for this question

Comment: @GigaSongulashvili hey, how did you connect it with laravel?

Comment: @VithuBati, what are the event1,event2,event3,event4 ? are they function names ? Like a function ( or a method ) you created that has http request ?

Comment: i did like this but i have problem updating my chat template, socket-io on Events not update my template correctly

Comment: Nevermind response from @MA-Maddin solve my problem and i think is the correct way to implement socket- io on Angular.

Comment: hello, here i found somebody has already implemented socket.io, may please check my code and tell me what is the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56963376/angular-8-using-sails-js-websokcet-sokcet-io

Answer (score 31):

## Implement socket.io-client as an Angular service

**Setup**

`npm install socket.io-client --save`

**Note (since Socket.IO v3):**
Do not install `@types/socket.io-client` since the types are now included in the `socket.io-client` package. So you will face problems if you install them additionally ([source](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-installation/)).

**The service:**

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { io, Socket } from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable()
export class ChatService {
  private socket: Socket;

  constructor() {
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
  }

  // EMITTER example
  sendMessage(msg: string) {
    this.socket.emit('sendMessage', { message: msg });
  }

  // HANDLER example
  onNewMessage() {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      this.socket.on('newMessage', msg => {
        observer.next(msg);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**In a component:**

```typescript
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChatService } from './chat-service';

@Component({
  // ...blabla...
})
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {
  msgInput: string = 'lorem ipsum';

  constructor(
    private chatService: ChatService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.chatService.onNewMessage().subscribe(msg => {
      console.log('got a msg: ' + msg);
    });
  }

  sendButtonClick() {
    this.chatService.sendMessage(this.msgInput);
  }
}
```

Comment: sendMessage(msg: string) {
    this.socket.emit('sendMessage', { message: msg });
  }                                                                                                                                                             How can i send acknowledgment here?

Comment: This is the correct implementation of socket-io because the first one dont work good when  updating the data in component's templates

Comment: hello, here i found somebody has already implemented socket.io, may please check my code and tell me what is the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56963376/angular-8-using-sails-js-websokcet-sokcet-io

Answer (score 4):

Following the solution of @MA-Maddin, I did this implementation:

**at Service**:socket.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketService {
private socket:SocketIOClient.Socket;

constructor() { 
  this.socket=io('http://localhost:3300');
}
emit(event:string, data:any){
  this.socket.emit(event,data);
}
on(event:string){
  return Observable.create(observer=>{
   this.socket.on(event,data=>{
    observer.next(data);
   });
  })
 }
}
```

**At Component**

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation} from 
'@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/auth/auth.service';
import Socket from '../../services/socket.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lobby-chat',
  templateUrl: './lobby-chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lobby-chat.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class LobbyChatComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private socket:Socket) {
  this.socket.on('getMessage').subscribe(data=>{
  console.log(data);
  });
  }
  pushMessage(msg){
  this.socket.emit('sendMessage',msg);
  }
}
```

This will update your bindings correctly.
Note: **use npm i "@types/socket.io-client for use or define Socket io Types **

Comment: hello, here i found somebody has already implemented socket.io, may please check my code and tell me what is the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56963376/angular-8-using-sails-js-websokcet-sokcet-io

Comment: FYI: Observer.create() is deprecated.

Comment: `private socket:SocketIOClient.Socket;` this line gives error? any solutions

Comment: estas haciendo algo que no entiendo, `private socket:SocketIOClient.Socket;` de donde estas trayendo el `SocketIOClient` ??????????

Comment: @Enzo instala los types de socket con el comando "npm i @types/socket.io-client"

Answer (score 3):

I know its an old question , For me none of the solutions worked so I solved with below approach.

**Do Not Waste your time** if your socket connection  polling is working fine and not getting any error , It might be due to the socket.io.client package conflict with your other setup

my application version are below.

`Angular 12.x` `Socket.io.client 4.x` `Node 14.16.1` 
I also tried with ngx-socket-io package too that also didn't work. the strange part is socket.io poling works well hand shaking are correct but not able to listen the event on new messages.

So my final approach is adding socket.io manully to index.html of angular and dispatch and event to the compoent.

```
function RsCustomEvent ( event, message ) {
    params = { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: message };
    var evt = document.createEvent( 'CustomEvent' );
    evt.initCustomEvent( event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail );
    return evt;
}
var socket = io('localhost:3000');
socket.on("channel-name", function (message) {
    window.dispatchEvent(RsCustomEvent('socketEventListen',message));

});
```

then in the angular component I used below codes.

```
 import { Observable , fromEvent} from 'rxjs';


fromEvent(window, 'socketEventListen').subscribe((data) =>{
 });
```

manually download the socket.io client js file and place that in asset folder and use the above codes.

Answer (score 2):

In addition the VithuBati's answer you need to install: 

`npm i socket.io-client --save
npm i @types/socket.io-client --save`

Comment: So I have to run the second cmd too? The "SocketIOClient.Socket" namespace is not found in my project...

Comment: Yep. the second is needed.

Comment: hello, here i found somebody has already implemented socket.io, may please check my code and tell me what is the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56963376/angular-8-using-sails-js-websokcet-sokcet-io