# Connect to socket using socket.io with angular 5

Tags: angular, socket.io

I have .net socket server , I successfuly connect to it using socket.io with angular ..but I cannot found how to send data to server and recieve from it ..can anyone help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use socket.io-client in angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47161589/how-to-use-socket-io-client-in-angular-4)

Answer (score 5):

Work with `Observables` and write an Angular service with methods to `listen` and `send` messages to the server:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import { Message } from '../model/message';

import * as socketIo from 'socket.io-client';

const SERVER_URL = 'https://yourserverhost.com/';

    @Injectable()
    export class SocketService {
        private socket;

        public initSocket(): void {
            this.socket = socketIo(SERVER_URL);
        }

        public send(message: Message): void {
            this.socket.emit('message', message);
        }

        public onMessage(): Observable<Message> {
            return new Observable<Message>(observer => {
                this.socket.on('message', (data: Message) => observer.next(data));
            });
        }
    }
```

Find a complete app using WebSockets, Node.js and Angular written entirely in TypeScript here: https://github.com/luixaviles/socket-io-typescript-chat

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

To send data to server you should use socket.**emit()** function something like this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.emit('server method', dataToSend);
});
```

To recieve data from server you should listen to server functions. For this purposes exists socket.**on()** method:

```
.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('server method', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});
```

You can read more about emitting and receiving data:
https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Here are some links using socket.io with angular project:
https://medium.com/@vipinswarnkar1989/socket-io-in-mean-angular4-todo-app-29af9683957f
https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/angular/angular-socket-io-tutorial/

Comment: Sorry but socket.on(‘connect’) not called in client side

Comment: Could you provide code, you used to connect to sockets?

Comment: import * as socketIo from ‘socket.io-client’; var socket = socketIo.connect(‘http://172.18.13.3:8080’)

Answer (score 0):

I needed this as well, and socket.io-client API does not fit very well in an angular app, and it should be wrapped with rxjs, IMHO.

So that's why I created a really tiny wrapper library.

https://github.com/harunurhan/rx-socket.io-client

You can use it like below:

```
const socket = new RxSocket('/url/to/socket.io/server');

const event$ = socket.subject('event_name'); // get rxjs/Subject for a specific event

event$.subscribe((data) => { // read data
  console.log(data.foo)
});

event$.next({foo: 'bar'}); // send data

// create observables for events that you want to only listen (receive data)
const event$ = socket.observable('event_name'); // get rxjs/Observable for a specific event

event$.subscribe((data) => { // read data
  console.log(data.foo)
});
```